# mySQL - limit on datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, limit

I have a mySQL table containing matchs and their dates (in a DateTime column).

Is it possible to get all matches from day X to X+n, and then all matches from day X+n to day X+2n...?

I would use that to "limit" my results: If I'm on page 1, I get all matches from day 1 to day 5 (for example), on page 2, I get all matches from day 6 to day 10 etc.

I guess I can't use the `LIMIT` clause because it only limits rows I get (based on a number of rows I want and not on a number of days)

Comment: Use `WHERE` clause instead then.

Comment: Keep in mind though that the number of items per date-range might vary. You wont have lets say 5 items per each page but a different number on every page.

Comment: ToBe is correct. Instead, you may want to consider using an `Order by` and then choose explicitely how many items to display per page. The order by will sort your data based on the column(s) that you choose. So `Order by date desc` will sort your data based on the date column and the desc specifies that it will be in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Well, I think I didn't explain right, then. Yes, I would like to have some fixed number of items per page: for example, on page 1, you have the next 5 days (where there are matchs, if there aren't any matchs on 1 day don't display it). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with the `DATE_ADD` function

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

**Edit:**

If you want to use it for pagination you can do it with the following:

```
$page = 0; //receive it i.e with $_GET, but be aware of sql injection
$intervalInDays = 30;
//create db connection...
$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date 
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE('your startdate'), INTERVAL (".$page * $interval.") DAY) 
    AND DATE_ADD(DATE('your startdate'), INTERVAL (".($page+1) * $interval.") DAY)";
//query and fetch...
```

Comment: And what to do if I want the X next days then, please? :p

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `BETWEEN` function in MySQL:

```
$start = 0;
$end = 5;

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE day 
  BETWEEN DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL $start DAY)
  AND DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL $end DAY)
```

Adjust the $start and $end variables as you wish using the page number.